# Invoking Facebook OAuth Dailog for FB 2.4

Tags: java, facebook

Can anybody help me to invoke Facebook OAuth Dailog for FB 2.4? I tried

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
                                  client_id=APP_ID
                                   &redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL
                                   &state=RANDOM_NUMBER_PREVENT_CSRF
                                   &scope=email
                                   &response_type=code
```

But I got error

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains

When I check the saml trace it seems I'm not getting a response from FB for the above request. Did I miss anything? Please advice me on this. Thanks

Comment: Could you give a little more information about what you mean by "saml trace"? How is this URL accessed?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct REDIRECT URL

Comment: @Jason: saml trace is a adone providing Firefox to track saml requests and responses.

Comment: @Juned:Yes this worked for me when invoking an app in FB v2.3 but does not work for FB v2.4

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, I would double check that the Redirect URI you're using in the Login Dialog is actually configured in your Facebook Application Settings.